# Change Sublime Text 3 packages path

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, windows

is it possible to change the default packages directory path in Sublime Text 3? 
For now, the default path is:

> C:\Users\my_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages

Would it be possible to change it ? For example to this:

> C:\my_folder

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did not think about the portable version. I tried this option and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

**For the non_portable version:**

1. QUIT Sublime Text 3
2. Delete the [Sublime Text 3] directory under C: \ Users \ Administrator \ AppData \ Roaming \ Sublime Text 3
3. Creat new folder [DATA] under installed [Sublime Text 3]
   as d:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\DATA\
4. Open Sublime Text 3 and then install the [Package Control] process,
   reference operate as https://packagecontrol.io/installation
5. Done. It change to \DATA\ folder

Comment: Does this actually CHANGE the non_portable to the portable version?

Comment: @agiopnl yes; if there's a `Data` folder (case is important on Linux) in the same location as the binary, Sublime uses that as the data folder instead of the "normal" location. This works across every platform and is what the portable Windows version is doing (other than not including an installer).

Answer (score 1):

The non-portable version of Sublime Text on [Windows uses the `USERPROFILE` environment variable to decide where to place the roaming folder](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/relocating-the-data-directory/21892/9).

So the only options are to set this environment variable to something else, create a directory junction, or use the portable version of ST.